# Invoke local function in a global function fashion?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to invoke a non-global function, in a global function fashion? (i.e. without using a qualifier)
e.g.

```
var lib = {
    notGlobalFn: function(){ /*...*/ }
};
var foobar = function(){
    notGlobalFn();
};
foobar();
```

I can think of three solutions myself (listed below), but I was hoping there would be another solution which didn't use global functions OR this. context OR subfunctions. Are there any other ways to do this? (Or have I put too many restrictions/am I being a pedant?)

My focus is on brevity and being able to define the foobar function, outside of the context of the lib (i.e. so I can define a library, and let people use it in a local context fashion).

**Test:** http://jsbin.com/denawa/5/edit?javascript,console

***Solution #1:*** - use a subfunction

Rejected because foobar is integrated into the lib.

```
var lib = function(){
  var notGlobalFn = function(){ /*...*/ }
  return {
    foobar: function(){
      notGlobalFn();
    }
  }
};
lib().foobar()
```

***Solution #2:*** - set/unset global function

Rejected because global functions are used.

```
notGlobalFn = lib.notGlobalFn
foobar();
notGlobalFn = undefined
```

***Solution #3:*** - use context

Rejected because they're using qualifiers.

```
var foobar = function(){
    this.notGlobalFn();
};
foobar.call(lib);

OR

var foobar = function(){
    lib.notGlobalFn();
};
foobar();
```

All in all, if I had to choose one of the above methods, I'd go with **Solution #2**.

****EDIT****

***Another Solution:*** - use a local variable (extension of Solution #3).

```
var foobar = function(){
  var notGlobalFn = lib.notGlobalFn
  notGlobalFn();
};
```

***And Another Solution:*** - add notGlobalFn to 'this' (I didn't think this would work).

```
function init(scope){
  scope.notGlobalFn = lib.notGlobalFn
}
var foobar = function(){
  init(this)
  notGlobalFn()
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `lib.notGlobalFn()`? I don't understand what you're doing here.

Comment: *this* is not "context", it's essentially a local variable that is set by the call when entering an execution context.

Comment: This question seems confused. ECMAScript is lexically scoped, execution contexts are defined by how functions are created, not by how they are called (e.g. closures). A "local" function can never masquerade as a global function because it will always have the outer function's execution context on its scope chain, see [*ECMA-262 §10.4 Establishing an Execution Context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4)

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear... instead of down votes, maybe people could ask for clarification. What specifically is confusing? (A simple no, citing the relevant documentation would be a valid answer.)

Comment: @Mathletics, nothing's wrong with lib.notGlobalFn(), I was wondering if there was a way I could invoke the function without having to qualify it with the "lib." part (i.e. be as brief as possible). For example, Solution #2 is able to achieve this - http://jsbin.com/denawa/7/edit?javascript,console .

Comment: You are losing clarity for some perceived brevity (though you are actually adding __more__ code in pursuit of brevity.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with. Not sure why this is getting downvoted/closed, no-one has asked for clarification!

```
function init(scope){
  scope.notGlobalFn = lib.notGlobalFn
}
var foobar = function(){
  init(this)
  notGlobalFn()
};
```

Comment: Why would you add all this confusing extra code? This is getting downvoted because it makes _no sense_.